# Find sum of all keys in Session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, key, sum

I am using a form to create several arrays in a Session. Each time the form is submitted a new _SESSION['item'][] is made containing a new array. The code for this:

```
$newitem = array (
    'id' => $row_getshoppingcart['id'] ,
    'icon' => $row_getimages['icon'],
    'title' => $row_getimages['title'],
    'medium' => $row_getshoppingcart['medium'],
    'size' => $row_getshoppingcart['size'],
    'price' => $row_getshoppingcart['price'],
    'shipping' => $row_getshoppingcart['shipping']);

$_SESSION['item'][] = $newitem;
```

There could be any number of item arrays based on how many times the user submits the form. How can I get the total of the key 'price' from every item in the entire session and echo it on the page?

Thank you in advance for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['item'] as $item)
    $sum += $item['price'];
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through them:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $item) {
    $total += $item['price'];
}
echo $total;
```